# What exactly is args ...interface{} means for a parameter of method?

Tags: go

I am referring to following method that takes last argument as args ...interfact{})

`func (*sqlx.DB).Select(dest interface{}, query string, args ...interface{}) error`

**https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#DB.Select**

From my understanding that the method accepts last parameter of any type which is variadic ..

So

```
    selectStmt = 'Select * FROM users where user_id IN (?)'
    selectStmt, userArgs, err := sqlx.In(selectStmt, userIDs)// userIDs is a slice
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "")
    }

    selectStmt = s.db.Rebind(selectStmt)


    var users []User
        err = s.db.Select(&users, selectStmt, userArgs) // wrong one .. Line A

    err = s.db.Select(&users, selectStmt, userArgs... ) // right one .. Line B
```

In the aforementioned code if i comment out Line B , but not Line A it doesn't work. I get following error.

- sql: converting argument $1 type: unsupported type []interface {}, a slice of interface *

### Question

What exactly happening here , why can't go infer the variadic automatically ?? What is the need of passing extra '...' to the third argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly happening here , why can't go infer the variadic automatically ?? What is the need of passing extra '...' to the third argument?

Go doesn't infer the variadic automatically - in fact, Go intentionally infers very little and does very little automatically. You need the `...` *because* it does not infer. It also makes clear, when you pass a slice to a variadic, whether you mean for it to be exploded, or you mean for the slice itself to be a single argument; either could be a valid use case, and rather than making assumptions, Go expects you to be explicit.